# Can you get the average order of $ \left( 1+|\mu(n)| \right)^{M(n)} $, where $\mu(n)$ and $M(n)$ are the Möbius and Mertens functions, respectively

Tags: summation, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory, mobius-function

When yesterday I was interested in do a little study about the arithmetic function $$f(n)=\left( 1+|\mu(n)| \right)^{M(n)},$$
defined for integers $n\geq 1$, which $\mu(n)$ is the **Möbius function** and $M(x)=\sum_{k\leq x}\mu(k)$, thus $M(n)$ is the **Mertens function**, I have doubts  about if my computations were interesting and if it is possible improve my study, but the **Question** (see below) is the main purpose for this post.

Combining  the fact that $\log  \left( 1+|\mu(n)| \right)$ is positive and bounded by $\log 2$ with the **Prime Number Theorem** I can prove that
$$\log f(n)=o(n).$$

I know from Wikipedia's Page for  [square-free integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) the (obvious) bound $$\mathcal{Q}(n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}n+O \left( \sqrt{n} \right) ,$$ where $\mathcal{Q}(x)$ is the number of square-free integers between 1 and $x$. I say this fact since I will accept it if you use/need it.

> **Question.** Can you get the asymptotyc behaviour (I say for example a big oh result, that is an asymptotic identity with error term denoted with a big oh notation) for 
>   $$\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\ n\text{ square-free}}}2^{M(n)}$$ 
>   as $x\to\infty$? Thus I am asking about the average order for $f(n)$. **Thanks in advance.**

With this exercise my purpose is learn about somethings related with **sieves**, if you can use it in your answer.

I don't know if such kind of questions were in the literature, perhaps the definition about $f(n)$ hasn't interesting properties.

**Appendix: (Is only a comment):** And this was my attempt to combine the definition of previous function $f(n)$ with the Riemann hypothesis:

An additional doubt is if the abscisse $\Re s>\frac{3}{2}$ is the best that I can state on assumption of the **Riemann hypothesis** when I want to state 
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{M(n)}{n^s}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\log \left( f(n-1) \right) }{ \left( \log \left( 1+|\mu(n-1)| \right)  \right)n^s }=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}-1.$$

Comment: In the most recent of myself posts, the user that answered the question can write differentlythe factor $1+|\mu(n)|$.

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding I say that I know that the mean $\sum_{k\leq n}f(k)$ is $$\left(n-\mathcal{Q}(n)\right)+\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\ n\text{ square-free}}}2^{M(n)}.$$ This site entertains lot! It is incredible.

Comment: The sum $\sum 2^{M(n)}$ is going to be dominated by the few terms for which $M(n)$ is largest; and we do not know the maximal order of $M(n)$ (indeed, knowing the maximal order would resolve the Riemann Hypothesis).

Comment: I accept your words, but **my purpose is that with your answer or the answer going from other users** leave some facts that I can learn, for example you say that *the sum is going dominated by the few terms...*, and I don't know how get this deduction. Also in my question I say that I want to learn some about sieves, I understand taht perhaps isn't possible, but my main purpose in this site is exploit the knowledge of other users, since from theirs answer I can learn some facts and easy computations. **Thus I relax my question, since I am looking learn.** Very thanks much @GregMartin

Comment: Fair enough—I'll add a little more detail here. Suppose the largest value of $M(n)$ for $n\le x$ is $L$. I claim that you can ignore all $n\le x$ for which $M(n) \le L-2\log x$, say. Indeed, the contribution of these $n$ is at most $x\cdot 2^{L-2\log x} = x\cdot x^{2\log2} 2^L = 2^L/x^{2\log2-1}$, which is asymptotically smaller than the single term $2^L$. This is one concrete manifestation of "the sum is dominated by the few largest terms".

Comment: As for the connection to the Riemann hypothesis: the statement that the Riemann zeta function has no zeros with real part greater than $\sigma$ is equivalent to the statement that $M(n) \ll n^{\sigma+\epsilon}$. Therefore any upper bound on $M(n)$ (which, as we saw before, is essentially the same as an upper bound on your sum) is equivalent to a zero-free region for the zeta function. At the moment, for example, we can't prove that your sum is less than $2^{n^{0.999}}$, even though we expect it to be only a little larger than $2^{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: With my eyes, I say that yours computations have valor. Perhaps from the viewpoint of a professional some questions that I am asking seem diffuse, but now your computations are here as reference of all users. Now I try read and understand your computations. Of course feel free to edit add an answer. Thanks @GregMartin